# Why dynamic created button not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a search page, when click the button, then it display the search result.
however, in the result page, when I continue to search for something, it seems that the button is not responding:

here is script:

```
    <div id="mainpage" >
    </div>

<script id="search" type="text/xml" >

                <div>

                    <input type="search" name="search" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="search" value=""/> 
                    <button id="searchButton" type="submit" onClick="app.navigate('#home/search',{trigger: true});">Search</button>

                </div>
                <div>

                    <table >
                           {{result}}
                    </table>

                </div>

  </script>
```

here is part render the page at back:

```
  if(route=='search'){

      var data = $.mobile.activePage.find("input[name=search]").val();
      /*

       code to filter the result

      */

      $('#mainpage').html(_.template($('#search').html())(    
      { 
            result: resultvalue }
      )); 



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is invalid is the first problem.

You're closing your `_.template` method call early.

Try replacing it with this:

```
if (route === 'search') {

    var data = $.mobile.activePage.find("input[name=search]").val();

    ...

    $('#mainpage').html(_.template($('#search').html(), {
        result: resultValue
    }));

}
```

EDIT

Try replacing the onclick event on your button with this:

```
onclick="app.navigate('#home/search',{trigger: true}); return false;"
```

Your onclick event was probably happening, but you weren't stopping the default behaviour of the submit button.

Comment: sorry, there are too many other files to make this script work....I only paste the part which related to this issue, just would like to know why rendered page does not accept second time onClick event

Comment: in the log, I didn't see the navigation happen...it only happen for the first time, then after I got the result page, when I continue to search something, after I click the button, in the log, it doesn't goes into that route scope...is it reason that the current url changed to home/search but navigate url is still trying navigate to the same url which caused the problem?

Comment: do you have any errors in your console? sounds like you've got a problem elsewhere in your app, and without seeing more code i probably won't be able to help you i'm afraid.